# Ownerdraw ComboBox Text Align Vertically Center

Tags: mfc

I am using owner-draw ComboBox in my MFC dialog based application.

I can draw Combobox's  ListBox items but I cant set the ComboBox text in the ComboBox's edit control with vertical center alignment, it always renders on the top left of the edit control.

I need the text to be rendered on vertical center in the edit control.

How to achieve it?
CombobOx style :- CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_OWNERDRAWFIXED | CBS_SORT | CBS_HASSTRINGS | CBS_UPPERCASE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP

```
BOOL CTestComboDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    COMBOBOXINFO cbi = { sizeof cbi};
    m_ctrlCombo.GetComboBoxInfo(&cbi);
    CRect r;
    CWnd* p = CWnd::FromHandle(cbi.hwndItem);
    ((CEdit*)p)->GetRect(&r);

    r.DeflateRect(10,10);
    ((CEdit*)p)->SetRect(r);
    m_ctrlCombo.AddString("GHKL");
    m_ctrlCombo.AddString("FGHJKL");
    m_ctrlCombo.AddString("ASDFGH");
    m_ctrlCombo.AddString("QWERTY");
    m_ctrlCombo.SetCurSel(0);
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMyComboBox::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    CDC dc;
    dc.Attach(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);

    LPCTSTR lpszText = (LPCTSTR) lpDrawItemStruct->itemData;
    ASSERT(lpszText != NULL);

    if (lpDrawItemStruct->itemID != -1)
        dc.DrawText(lpszText, strlen(lpszText),
        &lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem,
        DT_LEFT|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_VCENTER);
    dc.Detach();

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show the relevant code inside your question. Also the direct link isn't reachable, when you click on the link here.,

Comment: @xMRi, I have uploaded my sample in one drive and shared the link provided by Onedrive. The URL is valid only but when copying the link in stackoverflow.com website it becomes invalid.

Comment: I see no problems. the text should be vertically centered. But how large is you text (height)? And how large is the rectangle?

Comment: @xMRi the problem happens only in ownerdraw combobox not in the normal combobox

Comment: ;) Yes. Your code shows the ownerdraw stuff... but anyway, I see no problems here. Check the size of therect and the font size. Remember you don't select any font...

Comment: @xMRi. I did not select any font.If you are not facing any problem, could you please share your code.

Comment: I do nothig different than you, except selecting a font.

Comment: @xMRi what font and what size you used. I need solution without selecting any font. I want to use default font only.

Comment: I used the font set to the control  I Retrieve it with WM_GETFONT.

Answer (score 0):

The owner-drawn combo box control will be displayed taller than it is set in the dialog resource: default height of the combo box in the resource editor is 12 pixels, but in the running application it will be displayed 2 pixels taller.
So I used below code to adjust the height of the edit control of combobox and got the text vertically center aligned

```
TEXTMETRIC tm;
HDC hDC = ::GetDC(NULL);
CFont* pFont = GetFont();
HFONT hFontOld = (HFONT)SelectObject(hDC, pFont->GetSafeHandle());
GetTextMetrics(hDC, &tm);
SetItemHeight(-1,tm.tmHeight + tm.tmExternalLeading + 1);
SelectObject(hDC, hFontOld);
::ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```